# Is there a technical reason why code analysis can't figure out that this variable has been set?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I'm making an initial assignment to my reference-type variable inside an awaited lambda, like so:

```
private class TestClass {
    public int TestInt;
}

public async Task TestMethod() {
    TestClass testVar;

    await Task.Run(() => {
        testVar = new();
    });

    var testInt = testVar.TestInt;
}
```

However, the last line gives the error "Use of unassigned local variable 'testVar'".  Is there a technical reason why C#'s code analysis can't figure out that the variable is guaranteed to be assigned by that point?  It's kind of annoying to have the use the `!` operator wherever I first use `testVar`.  Is there any way to work round this if I need to first assign the variable inside an awaited lambda, and can't conveniently give it a default assignment (it's quite a complex class)?

Comment: From a syntactical perspective, you are not assigning `testVar` before the last line of that method. You are passing a lambda function that assigns it into another method, and awaiting that method. That's all that the compiler knows. It doesn't know whether the lambda will be run to completion before you get to the part where the variable is accessed, or whether it will be run at all. However, if you're confident that the variable will be assigned, why not just assign an initial value of `null` to it?

Comment: @JLRishe I was also considering this workaround, but it doesn't nicely work when nullable reference types are enabled. You'd either have to make `testVar` nullable or assign `null!` to it.

Comment: How about `var testVar = await Task.Run(() => { TestVar x = new(); return x; });`

Comment: @JLRishe That works in this case but I may be using a method taking a lambda that doesn't allow me to get the lambda's return value.

Comment: Cannot tell why it is like it is, but if I found that in code I am reviewing, I'd recommend to refactor that fundamentally. That starts with the `async void` and spans the convoluted assignment. Reason: in case of an error (assuming this is a simplification and by far not all that is happening here in the real thing) this is probably a debugging nightmare.

Comment: I changed it to `async Task`, the `async void` was a slip I made when typing the example.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the reason for this is that the C# flow analysis has no way of knowing that the lambda passed into `Task.Run` (or any awaited method taking a lambda) will be executed for sure by the time the `await` finishes, so it doesn't assume that it will be.  For this reason, I need to initialize the variable with `TestClass testVar = null!;` to assert that it will be non-null by the time I access it, to get rid of the warning/error.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is not an async/await issue but a general issue with lambda expressions. The compiler doesn't seem to be able to follow the path of the lambda to detect the assignment.

This code also doesn't compile:

```cs
        private class TestClass
        {
            public int TestInt;
        }

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            TestClass testVar;

            Action a = new Action(() =>
            {
                testVar = new();
            });
            a.Invoke();

            var testInt = testVar.TestInt; // Same here: "testVar" is not initialized
        }
```

So I first thought the compiler was generally unable to track assignments over method boundaries, but the following code surprisingly is ok:

```cs
public void TestMethod()
{
    TestClass testVar;

    void Foo()
    {
        testVar = new();
    }

    Foo();
    var testInt = testVar.TestInt; // No more complaints!
}
```

So this appears to be some limitation of the compiler regarding lambda functions, but why - I cannot tell.